# How to change a link's HREF using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a game, and I want to have something that the player can click to toggle the colors of the page. Specifically, I want to have the player be able to change the Bootstrap theme (following themes taken from Bootswatch) from Cerulean to Darkly to make the page style look different.

To do this I need to be able to change the HREF of the link using JavaScript. How would I do this exactly?

Comment: Are you sure, you want to change the href attribute? You can add a click handler to the link and toggle the class which is responsible for the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `twitter-bootstrap`, I assume you're using `jQuery`. You can change a `<link>`'s `href` attribute with a simple call:

`$("link[href=OLDHREFYOUWANTTOCHANGE]").attr("href", newURL.com)`

However, I'm afraid this won't necessarily reload the CSS for the page. Maybe you can set a `window.location.hash` for the website (or some other parameter) and have a certain set of stylesheets load depending on that.

For example, at the top of your page:

```
<script>
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash === "#blue")
        //add blue stylesheet
    else
        //add red stylesheet
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get it to work correctly is to simply reload the page and only load the specific css file as needed.

But you can add a new css file like this, not sure if it will work correctly in all cases since it won't reset your old css:

```
var link = $('<link>');
link.attr({
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: <your CSS file url>
});
$('head').append(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery use this:

```
$(location).attr('href','http://www.newurlorwhatever.com');
```